# How do I put a String value into List <Integer>?

Tags: java, string, list, generics, collections

I was challenged with a task to put a `String` value into `List<Integer>`. I am only allowed to use standard List format and Integer wrapper. How can I do this? Please. help.

Comment: „*I was challenged with a task to put a `String` value into `List<Integer>`...*“ — What is the purpose of such a *challenge*?

Comment: Currently, there are three different answers, each following an entirely different interpretation of your question. Please clarify what you want to achieve.

Comment: Sounds like a stupid "square peg in a round hole" challenge. My answer is: **You can't**. Same as you cannot put an `Apple` in a `List<Car>`. It simply doesn't fit (wrong type). Or rather, although the language can physically do it, because of backwards-compatibility issues, you should never, ever actually do so.

Answer (score 3):

If you use a raw type you can add anything you want to a list, with no type check.

```
List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<>();
List rawList = integerList;
rawList.add("string");
System.out.println(integerList);
```

Output: `[string]`

Comment: I recommend adding a “kids don’t do this at home” warning, explaining that this is only useful for the sake of such challenges but should never appear in production code. Further, it’s worth mentioning that the resulting situation has a name, [heap pollution](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/nonReifiableVarargsType.html#heap_pollution), to categorize the bugs that it will cause.

Answer (score -1):

You can use ASCII encoding to store the String data as Integers, if that is what you meant.

```
String str;
List<Integer> list;
//construct a new list and the desired string here...

for(int i=0; i<str.length; i++)
    list.addLast((int)str.charAt(i));
```

In order to recreate the string from the list you would need to append each character individually:

```
String res = "";
for(Integer c : list)
    res += (char)c;
```

Comment: The OP's task is „*to put **a `String` value** into `List<Integer>`*“. The type of your _`(int)str.charAt(i)`_ expression is not „***a `String` value***“.

Comment: Then I appologize as I misunderstood the question.